# Window not poping up

Tags: java, swing, file, jframe, inputstream

What am I missing in my code to make the window for the program show up? I need for a window to show up and show what files are currently being processed by the inputstream src that was converted to string compute, but the JFrame does not pop up when I execute my program? this is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Mover  {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {   

    String usb = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
    String user = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";
    File TS3S = new File(usb + "/Teamspeak 3");
    File TS3D = new File(user + "/TS3");
    File MinecraftLauncherS = new File(usb + "/Minecraft");
    File MinecraftLauncherD = new File(user);
    File ShortcutS = new File(usb + "/Shortcuts");
    File ShortcutD = new File(user);
    File MinecraftFilesS = new File(usb + "/minecraft files");
    File MinecraftFilesD = new File(user + "/Application Data");

    //make sure source exists
    if(!TS3S.exists()){

       System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
       //just exit
       System.exit(0);

    }else{

       try{
        copyFolder(TS3S,TS3D);
       }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //error, just exit
            System.exit(0);
       }
    }

    //make sure source exists
    if(!MinecraftLauncherS.exists()){

       System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
       //just exit
       System.exit(0);

    }else{

       try{
        copyFolder(MinecraftLauncherS,MinecraftLauncherD);
       }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //error, just exit
            System.exit(0);
       }
    }

    //make sure source exists
    if(!ShortcutS.exists()){

       System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
       //just exit
       System.exit(0);

    }else{

       try{
        copyFolder(ShortcutS,ShortcutD);
       }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //error, just exit
            System.exit(0);
       }
    }

    //make sure source exists
    if(!MinecraftFilesS.exists()){

       System.out.println("Directory does not exist.");
       //just exit
       System.exit(0);

    }else{

       try{
        copyFolder(MinecraftFilesS,MinecraftFilesD);
       }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //error, just exit
            System.exit(0);
       }
    }


    System.out.println("Done");
    Runtime.getRuntime ().exec (user + "/TS3/ts3client_win32.exe");
    System.exit(0);
    }

public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest)
    throws IOException{

    if(src.isDirectory()){

        //if directory not exists, create it
        if(!dest.exists()){
           dest.mkdir();
           System.out.println("Directory copied from " 
                          + src + "  to " + dest);
        }

        //list all the directory contents
        String files[] = src.list();

        for (String file : files) {
           //construct the src and dest file structure
           File srcFile = new File(src, file);
           File destFile = new File(dest, file);
           //recursive copy
           copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);
        }

    }else{
        //if file, then copy it
        //Use bytes stream to support all file types
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest); 

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes 
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
               out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("File copied from " + src + " to " + dest);

            //read it with BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br
                = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String compute;
            while ((compute = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(compute);

                JFrame a = new JFrame("Current Files");
                a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JLabel process = new JLabel(compute);
                process.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (300, 100));
                a.getContentPane().add(process, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                a.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                a.pack();
                a.setVisible(true);
        } 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the biggest problem with your Swing code is:

- You're not following Swing's threading rule where the Swing code is called on the event thread, and all other long-running processes are called on background threads. Not doing this will effectively freeze your Swing GUI.
- More of a nitpick: You seem to be popping up many JFrames rather than simply display one JFrame and in it show the file names, perhaps in a JTextArea. If I were the user of the program, I'd appreciate you're doing the latter and not the former.

Consider

- Creating a separate class for your GUI code, one without static members.
- In this GUI have fields to get input from the user, including the source and destination directories, possibly pre-filled with default values.
- create and display your Swing GUI on the EDT, and let the user press a JButton to get things started,
- do your file processing in a background thread, such as that provided by a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/),
- from the background thread, publish to the event thread the file names that are being acted on,
- then display that information in the displayed JFrame, again perhaps in a JTextArea that is held by a JScrollPane.

Answer (score 0):

Hovercraft Full Of Eels is right. If you take only the code which opens the JFrame, it *does* show up.